# AdornerDecorator that lets some adorners pass?

Tags: .net, wpf, .net-3.5, adorner, adornerdecorator

**Question**: Is it possible to create an `AdornerDecorator` that takes only the `Adorner`s I want to its `AdornerLayer`?

```
public class SimpleCircleBehavior : Behavior<TextBox>
{
    private SimpleCircleAdorner sca;
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(AssociatedObject_Loaded);
    }

    void AssociatedObject_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        sca = new SimpleCircleAdorner(AssociatedObject);
        AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(AssociatedObject).Add(sca);
    }
}

public class SimpleCircleAdorner : Adorner
{
    // Be sure to call the base class constructor.
    public SimpleCircleAdorner(UIElement adornedElement)
        : base(adornedElement)
    {
    }

    // A common way to implement an adorner's rendering behavior is to override the OnRender
    // method, which is called by the layout system as part of a rendering pass.
    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        Rect adornedElementRect = new Rect(this.AdornedElement.DesiredSize);

        // Some arbitrary drawing implements.
        SolidColorBrush renderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
        renderBrush.Opacity = 0.2;
        Pen renderPen = new Pen(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Navy), 1.5);
        double renderRadius = 5.0;

        // Draw a circle at each corner.
        drawingContext.DrawEllipse(renderBrush, renderPen, adornedElementRect.TopLeft, renderRadius, renderRadius);
        drawingContext.DrawEllipse(renderBrush, renderPen, adornedElementRect.TopRight, renderRadius, renderRadius);
        drawingContext.DrawEllipse(renderBrush, renderPen, adornedElementRect.BottomLeft, renderRadius, renderRadius);
        drawingContext.DrawEllipse(renderBrush, renderPen, adornedElementRect.BottomRight, renderRadius, renderRadius);
    }
}
```

How can I add `AdornerDecorator` inside a `TextBox`, and put that adorner inside that layer? Inside the behavior of course, designer shouldn't care about adding `AdornerDecorator` on *all* elements that have adorners...

Preferably only *this* adorner should go there, and not steal all other adorners.

### You cannot predict *when creating adorners* which layer the adorner appears...

Unless you *create `AdornerDecorator`*. Thats it! You can't know in advance on *which layer* they appear, they are not designed to work that way. This makes the whole thing just plain agony.

Imagine that you are creating adorner that *works only on `TextBox`*. To make it work and act along the `TextBox` you need `AdornerDecorator` to keep your adorners on top of `TextBox`.

1. How do you create `AdornerDecorator` to wrap element you are about to adorn? Oh yeah, that is *not* possible (not that I know of) during creation of adorner.
2. If you somehow manage to create `AdornerDecorator` you still have problems: it **steals all the adorners** in childs, and puts to this layer. Once again... WTF! How can I assume that all child element adorners, even the once I have not created, should go to this layer?

Other words, there are no way to control which layer your adorner appears if you don't specifically *know all child elements and their adorners* also. Thats whole *lot of knowing* when creating innocent sprinkles.

### Workaround possibility:

1. Create *special* `AdornerDecorator` that grabs *only the adorners we know we want on it*, others it would let go to next "global" AdornerDecorator.
2. Somehow make the adorner wrap the inners of adorned element with this decorator, and add our adorners *just* inside this decorator.

I don't like this workaround, but bad design decisions sometimes need very ugly hacks... I think this time we need this.

Comment: What exactly do you need help with? Perhaps stash some code in the rant.

Comment: No, I'm wondering is it possible to create AdornerDecorator that grabs only certain adorners...